# JavaScript - Recursively Finding Parent Nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an app written with JavaScript. In this app, I have a tree of JavaScript objects. An example tree and the code below can be seen in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/4919/).

I am trying to write a function that will return a list of IDs that are the ancestors. The ancestors of a element with a specific ID. Currently, I have the following:

```
function getAncestors(childId, branch) {
  var ancestors = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < branch.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < branch[i].children.length; j++) {
      if (branch[i].children[j].id === childId) {
        ancestors.push(branch[i].id);
        return ancestors;
      } else {
        var _ancestors = getAncestors(childId, branch[i].children);
        for (var k = 0; k < _ancestors.length; k++) {
          if (ancestors.indexOf(_ancestors[k]) === -1) {
            ancestors.push(_ancestors[k]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return ancestors;
}
```

It always returns the first parent. However, it doesn't return all ancestors. For example, in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/4919/), I'm trying to get an array that contains: [201, 2], in that order. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly though. I keep staring at this and it looks correct. But, obviously, it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working code (using iteration):

```
function getAncestors(childId, newbranch) {
    for (var i = 0; i < newbranch.length; i++) { // Search all branches
        var branch = newbranch[i];

        if (branch.id === childId) {
            return [];
        } else {
            if (branch.children && branch.children.length) {
                var x;

                if ((x = getAncestors(childId, branch.children)) !== false) {
                    x.push(branch.id)
                    return x;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Result:

```
[201,2]
```

Edit (shorter)

```
function getAncestors(childId, branch) {
    var i, ancestors;

    for (i = 0; !ancestors && branch && i < branch.length; i++) {
        if (branch[i].id === childId) return [];
        ancestors = getAncestors(childId, branch[i].children);
        if (ancestors) ancestors.push(branch[i].id);
    }
    return ancestors;
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution presented so far. It can be shortened even more. If you don't mind I would edit in a slightly optimized variant?

Comment: @Tomalak ok, fell free to optimize it (maybe add the optimized version to the end in a new `block` code)

Comment: Feel free to take the shortened version as your own, since it effectively is your own.

Comment: @Tomalak I edited your version with push instead unshift cause u were reversing the order

Comment: Yeah, I did that on purpose. I would expect to get the ancestors top down, but that's entirely a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach with a callback for [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and the actual parents.

```js
function getParents(id, array) {
    function iter(parents) {
        return function (a) {
            if (a.id === id) {
                result = parents;
                return true;
            }
            return a.children && a.children.some(iter([a.id].concat(parents)));
        };
    }

    var result;
    array.some(iter([]));
    return result;
}

var tree = [{ id: 1, name: 'Left', children: [{ id: 100, name: 'C1', children: [{ id: 1000, name: 'C2A', children: [] }, { id: 1001, name: 'D2A', children: [] }, { id: 1002, name: 'C2B', children: [] }] }, { id: 101, name: 'C2', children: [{ id: 2000, name: 'D7B', children: [] }, { id: 2001, name: 'E2A', children: [] }, { id: 2002, name: 'C2X', children: [] }] }] }, { id: 2, name: 'Middle', children: [{ id: 200, name: 'Z1', children: [{ id: 3000, name: 'R2A', children: [] }, { id: 3001, name: 'DYA', children: [] }, { id: 3002, name: 'Q2B', children: [] }] }, { id: 201, name: 'X2', children: [{ id: 4000, name: 'DMA', children: [] }, { id: 4001, name: 'ELA', children: [] }, { id: 4002, name: 'CRX', children: [] }] }] }, { id: 3, name: 'Right', children: [{ id: 300, name: 'Z1', children: [{ id: 5000, name: 'F7A', children: [] }, { id: 5001, name: 'EW5', children: [] }, { id: 5002, name: 'D5B', children: [] }] }, { id: 301, name: 'X2', children: [{ id: 6000, name: 'OMA', children: [] }, { id: 6001, name: 'NLA', children: [] }, { id: 6002, name: 'MRX', children: [] }] }] }];

console.log(getParents(4001, tree));
```

Version without moving an array, but with a marker for the actual depth. The result is now reversed.

```js
function getParents(id, array) {
    function iter(depth) {
        return function (a) {
            result[depth] = a.id;
            if (a.id === id) {
                result.length = depth;
                return true;
            }
            return a.children && a.children.some(iter(depth + 1));
        };
    }

    var result = [];
    return array.some(iter(0)) && result;
}

var tree = [{ id: 1, name: 'Left', children: [{ id: 100, name: 'C1', children: [{ id: 1000, name: 'C2A', children: [] }, { id: 1001, name: 'D2A', children: [] }, { id: 1002, name: 'C2B', children: [] }] }, { id: 101, name: 'C2', children: [{ id: 2000, name: 'D7B', children: [] }, { id: 2001, name: 'E2A', children: [] }, { id: 2002, name: 'C2X', children: [] }] }] }, { id: 2, name: 'Middle', children: [{ id: 200, name: 'Z1', children: [{ id: 3000, name: 'R2A', children: [] }, { id: 3001, name: 'DYA', children: [] }, { id: 3002, name: 'Q2B', children: [] }] }, { id: 201, name: 'X2', children: [{ id: 4000, name: 'DMA', children: [] }, { id: 4001, name: 'ELA', children: [] }, { id: 4002, name: 'CRX', children: [] }] }] }, { id: 3, name: 'Right', children: [{ id: 300, name: 'Z1', children: [{ id: 5000, name: 'F7A', children: [] }, { id: 5001, name: 'EW5', children: [] }, { id: 5002, name: 'D5B', children: [] }] }, { id: 301, name: 'X2', children: [{ id: 6000, name: 'OMA', children: [] }, { id: 6001, name: 'NLA', children: [] }, { id: 6002, name: 'MRX', children: [] }] }] }];

console.log(getParents(4001, tree));
```

Comment: This is terse but there's a small drawback: It creates a large amount of throw-away arrays. For large trees I would expect a performance penalty. For small trees it won't make much of a difference.

Comment: the maximal count of arrays is equal to the depth of the recursion.

Comment: That's not true, it creates a new array with every call of concat, or does it not? (Not sure now)

Comment: yes, but i dont't think that is a problem with performance, because the lenght of the arrays is small. but i could change it to a static array.

Comment: I would have set up a jsPerf test case but I can't log into GitHub right now, unfortunately, and that's the only way to access the site it seems. :-|